# I have engine revs problems with my 1999 Grand Vitara 2.5 L manual

Tags: manual-transmission, suzuki, grand-vitara

I have a manual transmission and when I pressed acceleration the RPM goes up but it takes awhile for it to drop back down until I shift what is the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds, from the little information you've given us, that the clutch is going out.